# Debugging why apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict shows up during fastlane

Tags: android, fastlane, google-play-console

I have the following fastlane

```
desc "Assemble Build, Test Application, and Run On Device"
lane :assemble do 
  assemble_build
  tests
end

desc "Assemble Build"
lane :assemble_build do |options|
  gradle(task: "assemble", build_type: @build_type)
end

desc "Run tests in Firebase Test Lab"
lane :tests do
  firebase_test_lab_android(
    project_id: "mobile-project",
    gcloud_service_key_file: "client-secret.json",
    app_apk: "app/build/outputs/apk/release/app-release.apk",
    type: "robo",
    devices: [ { model: "Pixel2", version: "28" } ]
  )
end

desc "Assemble Build, Test Application, and Run On Device, Upload App Store"
lane :master_release do 
    gradle(task: "clean assembleRelease")
    upload_to_play_store(track: "internal", skip_upload_metadata: true, skip_upload_images: true, skip_upload_screenshots: true)
    tests
end
```

- On my dev branch I run: `bundle exec fastlane assemble release:true`
- On my master branch I run: `bundle exec fastlane master_release release:true`

For some reason, once my branch get's to master, I get the following error:

> Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict: APK specifies a version code that has already been used. - APK specifies a version code that has already been used.

This error is basically saying that my `versionCode` in `defaultConfig { }` in `android/app/build.gradle` has already been used.

The only way to fix this is to push directly to master a new version code because apparently during the `dev` push, the release get's uploaded to Google to the point where it says the version code has already been used.

Does anyone know where this is so I can understand why this is happening? I was under the impression that the version code only get's sent when I upload to the Playstore.

Answer (score 0):

we ran into exactly the same problem. Specifically, we have CircleCI daily builds and release builds, corresponding to beta-release and production-release, respectively. They went quite well until a recent production release to Playstore around a week ago. Internally, both daily build and release build will fetch the latest version code from the beta channel and increase it by 1, then push the new build with the new version code to play store beta channel and production channel, respectively. The new problem is that the latest version code of the beta channel doesn't get updated after a production release.

Let's say we are going to have daily builds 569 -> 570 -> 571 -> 572 -> ...
then on top of the 570 build, we decide to kick off a new release build and eventually release it as v571. However, the latest version code the daily build could "see" is always 570, as a result, increase it to 571 and release to beta now conflicts with the v571 production release due to "Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict: APK specifies a version code that has already been used. - APK specifies a version code that has already been used."

Btw, in the old days, the daily build will see 571 instead of 570, so the next beta release(572) will never conflict with v571 in the production channel.

Not clear it's a Fastlane issue or Google API issue, but what I can assure is that it's caused by a recent change from either Fastlane or Google.

Update: Beta version code is typically greater than, or at least equals to, the production version code. However, for some still unknown reasons, the version code recently returned from 
 google_play_track_version_codes is an integer, which is used to be an array of strings and now is supposed to be an array of integers, AND beta version code is less than production version code. As a result, we need to compare the two and use the bigger one as the new version code.
see also: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/commit/552f0fa51aed24fbc349fa873b721ef8b73386ae

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but I'm not sure I understand. Because the issue is happening during a simple dev check that has no interaction with the Google Play Store ;\

Comment: It appears to me that the error "Google Api Error: apkNotificationMessageKeyUpgradeVersionConflict: APK specifies a version code that has already been used. - APK specifies a version code that has already been used." happens only when the new version code conflicts with the one being used in Google Play Store.

Comment: In our case, we noticed the latest fastlane(v2.136.0) release notes related to "version codes",  the change #15647 https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/pull/15647 has something to do with our daily build failures. The fix is either downgrading fastlane version or taking the greater of beta or production version code. we take the latter as a fix.